# Change a CSS selectors child on hover in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

With this basic jQuery code below, how would I make the on `mousout` change the item back to `display:none`?

Also can this be improved?

Any help please

```
$(".image").hover(function() {
      $(this).children(".image p").css({ display: 'inline' });
});
```

On the jQuery docs site I saw this: `$(selector).hover(handlerIn, handlerOut)` but I don't understand how to apply it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(".image").hover(function() {
      $(this).children(".image p").show();
}, function() {
      $(this).children(".image p").hide();
});
```

But why not use pure CSS for it?

```
.image:hover .image p { display:inline; }
```

Comment: I wanted to use CSS but I couldn't get it to work for some reason

Comment: Why not create another question and a jsfiddle with your html+css? I'm sure someone will be able to help you.

Comment: Also I didn't know that you cold put a hover event on a list of selectors like that, I thought you could only add :hover to the last item so thanks I learned something

Answer (score 2):

You don't need 2 functions if you test the event:

```
$(".image").hover(function(e) {
      $(this).children("p").toggle(e.type === 'mouseenter');
});
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/U5QGU/

I also simplified the selector because you don't need:

```
.image p
```

Because you already know that its parent has .image

You could also do this instead of toggle:

```
$(".image").hover(function(e) {
      $(this).children("p")[e.type === 'mouseenter' ? 'show' : 'hide']();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U5QGU/1/

Answer (score 1):

ThiefMaster is correct also but this is exactly as you asked for it:

```
$(".image").hover(function() {
      $(this).children(".image p").css({display:'inline'});
}, function() {
      $(this).children(".image p").css({display:'none'});
});
```

Comment: Well he obviously wants to hide/show so those methods are more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using children is to provide selector context:

```
$(".image").hover(function() {
    $("p", this).css({ display:'visible' });
}, function() {
    $("p", this).css({ display:'none' });
});
```

To use a single function as suggested by shredder:

```
$(".image").hover(function(e) {
    var d = (e.type === 'mouseenter') ? 'visible' : 'none';
    $("p", this).css({ display: d });
});
```